# Which data structure to use for the following class

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, set

I have both of these classes given (below in the code blocks) and I have to implement the given methods of TTEvent in no longer then O(log(N). I am allowed to use the following data structures:

- Integer[] - Array of start points or durations
- List, queue, dequeue or set - of start points or durations
- Map - mapping of start point to end point or duration
- Map - mapping of start point to time interval
- TTinterval[] - Array of time interval
- List, queue, dequeue or set - of time interval

There where also some mapping of duration to xyz, but since duration is not unique I excluded those immediately.

I am allowed to use subtypes like linked list, array list, hashmap etc.

I can't seem to find a fitting data structure to use. I mostly get stuck up on the methods that get passed a duration. All the ways I can think of finding data in those structures would be slower then O(log(N), mainly O(N), since I would either loop or call `.contain(value)` on a map.

It is to assume that N will be large rather then small.

Now ofc I don't want a solution, but some pointers as to what would be the most desired structure to use and maybe some tips specifically regarding the methods which pass a duration.

Java compiler has to be 1.8 if that makes any difference (jre/jdk 1.8)

```
    package tp;

    /**
    * Non changeable time-interval. start and end time-points are considered inclusive.
    */
    public class TTInterval {

      private final int start;

      private final int end;

      private final int duration;

      /**
       * Constructor.
       * 
       * @param start startpoint
       * @param end endpoint
       */
      public TTInterval(int start, int end) {
          this.start = start;
          this.end = end;
          this.duration = end - start + 1; // end inklusive
      }

      /**
       * @return startpoint
       */
      public int getStart() {
          return start;
      }

      /**
       * @return endpoint
       */
      public int getEnd() {
          return end;
      }

      /**
       * @return length
       */
      public int getDuration() {
          return duration;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "[(" + start + "-" + end + ")," + "{" + duration + "}]";
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
          final int prime = 31;
          int result = 1;
          result = prime * result + end;
          result = prime * result + start;
          return result;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
          if (this == obj) {
              return true;
          }
          if (obj == null) {
              return false;
          }
          if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
              return false;
          }
          TTInterval other = (TTInterval) obj;
          if (end != other.end) {
              return false;
          }
          if (start != other.start) {
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      }

    }
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

/**
 * An event consists of a unchangeable name and a collection of time intervals to which it happens.
 * 
 * It delivers information regarding its assigned time intervals.
 * 
 */
public class TTEvent {

    private final String title; 
    private final LinkedHashMap<Integer, TTInterval> intervals; //not sure if this is a good way



    /**
     * constructor.
     * 
     * @param title - name of the event
     */
    TTEvent(String title, String[] attributes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.intervals = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, TTInterval>();
    }


    /**
     * Checks if the provided time-interval (defined by startSlot and endSlot) coincides with any time- 
     *interval already assigned to the event.
     *
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param startSlot startpoint (inclusive) of the interval to check
     * @param endSlot endpoint (inclusive) of the interval to check
     * 
     * @return true, if there is a collision, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean conflictingInterval(int startSlot, int endSlot) {
        boolean result = false;
        while ((startSlot <= endSlot) && !result) {
            result = intervals.containsKey(startSlot);
            startSlot++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given time interval to the event (defined by startSlot and endSlot)
     * 
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param startSlot startpoint (inclusive) 
     * @param endSlot endpoint (inclusive) 
     * 
     * @pre endSlot &ge; startSlot
     * @pre startSlot &amp; endSlot &ge; 0
     */
    void addTimeInterval(int startSlot, int endSlot) {
        assert startSlot <= endSlot;
        assert startSlot >= 0;
        assert !conflictingInterval(startSlot, endSlot);

        intervals.put(startSlot, new TTInterval(startSlot, endSlot));
    }

    /**
     * Removes the time interval referenced by the startpoint and returns the removed time interval
     *
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param startSlot startpoint
     * @pre startSlot &ge; 0
     * @return the removed time interval, or null, if there was none
     */
    TTInterval removeTimeInterval(int startSlot) {
        assert startSlot >= 0;

        return intervals.remove(startSlot);
    }



    /**
     * If the given time point is used by the event, then the time interval which includes the time point 
     * is returned
     * 
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param timeslot the time point to look for
     * @pre timeslot &ge; 0
     * 
     * @return time interval which includes the time point, or null, if there is none
     */
    public TTInterval getIntervalContaining(int timeslot) {
        assert timeslot >= 0;

    }


    /**
     * Returns the (time wise)  first time interval which has the duration to look for.
     * 
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param duration - exact duration of the time interval to look for (in time slots)
     * @pre duration &gt; 0
     * 
     * @return First time interval with the specified duration, or null, if there is none
     */
    public TTInterval getfirstIntervalByDuration(int duration) {
        assert duration > 0;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the (time wise) first time interval which is the closest to the min-duration to look for 
     * (so the time interval with the shortest fitting min-duration)  So the duration of the returned 
     * time interval is equal or longer then the min-duration to look for.
     * 
     * This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals).
     * 
     * @param minDuration exact duration of the time interval to look for (in time slots)
     * @pre minDuration &gt; 0
     * @return First time interval with the desired minduration or longer, or null, if there is none
     */
    public TTInterval getfirstIntervalByMinDuration(int minDuration) {
        assert minDuration > 0;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
    }

}
```

Comment: So which methods do need to be within O(log(n))?

Comment: All the methods of TTEvent, wich have "This method has to work in O(log(N)) (N = number of time intervals)." in the comment. I excluded all other methods from the class, so it should be pretty much all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct, I'd suggest using a List as data structure, because it's expandable and you're able to get a sorted representation of it fairly easy. Also I would suggest you to sort your List(s) as well as for the search problems I'd suggest using [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) since its O(log n). So if you're inserting elements into your list search their respective position and use `List.add(index,element)`[Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) to add it at said position. Same goes for searching elements, just without the adding.

Comment: Aren't lists super slow tho? According to the chart I was given, List.add(int, E) is O(N) anywhere not end of the list. Same for remove.

Comment: This depends on which List you are using, a CopyOnWriteArrayList is just as you sad very slow in most demands. A LinkedList however is very fast in adding and removing elements. And an ArrayList is very fast for adding and getting elements. I'd suggest you taking a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-complexity) website for further detail, so you can decide which List you're going to use when.